# GraphQL and Styled Components syntax highlighting in web-mode?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, web-mode

How can I add syntax highlighting for GraphQL and Styled Components in web-mode?

Right now it doesn't work, which makes programming much less convenient, and it's surprisingly difficult to find the answer.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried?